# Data Transfer from Sql Server to Elasticsearch with SSIS and CData

Tags: elasticsearch, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2012, cdata-drivers

I am trying to data transfer from **Sql Server** to **Elasticsearch** with **SSIS**(Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services) application using CData Elasticsearch Destination tool.

What I am successfully for now.

- Using SSIS I am getting data from Sql Server.
- Using SSIS I am getting index names from Elasticsearch cluster.

But When I try to send data from Sql Server to Elasticsearch cluster. I am getting this **error** message

> SSIS package "c:\users...\visual studio 2015\Projects\Integration
> Services Project2\Integration Services Project2\Package.dtsx"
> starting. Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline:
> Validation phase is beginning. Error: 0xC001000E at Package: The
> connection "{D7065178-0114-46AA-ABF5-5D21C91A7582}" is not found. This
> error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection
> element is not found.
>
> Error: 0xC004800B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cannot find the
> connection manager with ID "{D7065178-0114-46AA-ABF5-5D21C91A7582}" in
> the connection manager collection due to error code 0xC0010009. That
> connection manager is needed by "CData Elasticsearch
> Destination.Connections[Elasticsearch 2020 Connection]" in the
> connection manager collection of "CData Elasticsearch Destination".
> Verify that a connection manager in the connection manager collection,
> Connections, has been created with that ID.
>
> Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: CData
> Elasticsearch Destination failed validation and returned error code
> 0xC004800B. Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or
> more component failed validation. Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task:
> There were errors during task validation. SSIS package
> "c:\users...\visual studio 2015\Projects\Integration Services
> Project2\Integration Services Project2\Package.dtsx" finished:
> Failure. The program '[8508] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with
> code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Seems like connection issue, the package is unable to find connection details. How is the package executed (by using SQL Server Agent job or something else)? Can you share some screenshots from the package, ssis project structure and the way you execute the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed **Run64BitRuntime True** from **Sample Project Property Page** > **Debugging**  and problem solved. Here is the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI5JL.png)